# Add color bar for ggplot2 facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a color bar for each strip of the ggplot2 facets, like this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ drv) + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) + 
  # Add a line on top (Inf) of the plot (Suggested by PoGibas)
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Inf, color = drv), size = 4)
```

[image]

But I need to add a gap between the color bar and the facet. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the same principle and add another `geom_hline()` but set `color="white"`, like this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ drv) + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Inf), color = "white", size=4) + # white space
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Inf, color = drv), size = 2)
```

Play with `size` to increase the "spacing".

[image]